# Javascript Counters starts on scroll

Tags: javascript

I need this counter starts on the scroll, not before. Is it possible?

```js
function startCounter(){
    $('.counter').each(function (index) {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 2000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(Math.round(now*10)/10);
            }
        });
    });
}   

startCounter();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="counter">92.2</span>
```

Comment: did you tried window.onscroll?

Comment: Not a pro on javascript, what should I do?

Comment: `window.onscroll = function () {
    //your code
};` try this

Comment: Hi there, is not working, the counters keep counting up and down forever...

Answer (score 3):

Call the function from inside the scroll event listener

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
  // you could do startCounter(); here
  // maybe you want to check the event or the scroll position (window.scrollY)
  // maybe you pass the event to the startCounter(event) function
  console.log('scroll is happening, window.scroll position is:', window.scrollY)
});
```

```html
<div style="height:10000px;width:200px;background-color:orange">just a big div to let the scroll appear</div>
```

For more information about the scroll event see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event

Answer (score 1):

This will do it for you.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    startCounter();
});
```

Comment: Haha, sorry
I had the window open some time before, and didn't see your answer before posting. Sorry about that.

Comment: It's crazy, the counters goes up and then down all the time

Comment: @JAVIERMARTINBALSA It's being fired at every scroll event. You can use some boolean variable such as `alreadyUsed = true/false` to check and prevent it from running more than once.